# Pokemon Go doesn't work on my android device

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go, android

It seems like Pokemon Go doesn't work on my HTC One M7. The app flashes and quits to my home screen immediately every time when I trying to open the app. I have never seen the Niantic sign and loading screen on my phone yet. The specification of this phone includes 2GB ram, 32GB storage, Qualcomm cpu and android version (5.0.2). Google Play store shows that this app is compatible with my device.

Comment: Have you cleared the game cache? Have you tried reinstalling? Is it version 0.29.0 or 0.29.2?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried to clear game data as well as cache, but it doesn't help. And I have reinstalled the game several times, including both 0.29.0 & 0.29.2 versions, it is still not working.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: 
If the device is rooted, you may need to unroot it and restore to stock Android because you will want the latest OTA updates. 
Uninstall the app. 
Make sure your system AND services are up to date. Manually check for updates. 
Then wipe the cache partition via the bootloader. Be sure to use the bootloader because even though the regular UI may allow you to wipe the cache partition, it sometimes misses things and isn't as clean (sources: I worked in Google Play tech support). Instructions here: http://droider.eu/2015/02/25/how-to-wipe-cache-partition-on-htc-one-m7-with-lollipop/. **
Reboot the device. 
Reinstall the app. 
I did this with my husband's phone - HTC One M7 Google Play Edition, same specs as yours - and now Pokemon Go works on it. YMMV and all that, but it's worth a try. 
**Wiping your cache partition does not remove any app data or change any settings; it removes legacy system data from previous software versions which may have been causing conflicts with the current versions. 
Let me know if this works for anyone else, I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a great deal of difficulty getting logged onto the servers and had tried every trick I could think of (clearing cache, going in and out of airplane mode, etc).  Finally I wondered if another app might be preventing the game from launching properly.  I removed AVAST mobile from my phone and now I can get in pretty regularly.  There are still times when the servers are too busy but even that has gotten better.